# A curious case of random number.. arcRandom( )

Tags: ios, iphone, epoch, arc4random

I came across a bug in in a app which i was reviewing the bug was

```
unsigned int i = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",(unsigned int) arc4random()]substringToIndex:2] integerValue]*[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

this line of code which uses epoch time and arc4random() gives random no on simulator but on device returns a constant value 4294967295 every time.

though the bug itself was easy to solve but this mystery about the device and simulator difference is unsolvable for me i think it has to do with i386 vs armv.

Any explanation will be helpful.

Comment: This wasn't a 32 bit / 64 bit difference, was it?

Comment: try with (double)arc4random()...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i think so ...

Comment: @amar Then you should be able to reproduce this on a simulator with the hardware matching the device, but perhaps the constant value would be different (what you see now is a -1 reinterpreted as an unsigned number).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger int1 = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",(unsigned int) arc4random()]substringToIndex:2] integerValue] ;
NSTimeInterval t = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] ;
double dd = t * int1 ;
NSLog(@"%f", dd) ;
```

`unsigned int` is not enough to place the value which is the result of integer * double.

Comment: @amar I think it just an coincidence that when you run you program on simulator, `NSInteger int1 = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",(unsigned int) arc4random()]substringToIndex:2] integerValue] ;` return an less value.

Comment: maxing out seems to be the issue